# git: command to run on specific files changes on local machine

Tags: git, automation

I have a git repo with multiple projects in it.

Sometimes when I merge from master into my branch the incoming changes includes changes that require me to rebuild specific projects or re-run some scripts in order to make the the whole project run correctly on my local machine.

I would like to automate this process by checking the changes and running the correct action for each change.

For Example:
If a web client files changed, automatically run `npm install` and `npm build`.
If a db migration file changed, run the db migration tool.

I don't want to run all my actions on every change because it may take a while, I want specific actions on specific files changes. I also want it to check the files on every git action (merge/rebase/checkout/revert...)

Is there any way to create such automation using git?

Comment: Git is a version control system, not a build or CI system. Build and CI systems are designed for your problem. Version control systems ... aren't. Kind of like the difference between a warehouse (Git) and a truck (build/CI): you need both to get the job done, but you wouldn't drive a warehouse, nor store goods long term in a truck.

Comment: I agree that maybe git alone is not the answer but I know git supports client side hooks like `pre-rebase` or `pre-commit` I thought maybe it supports something that will be more "general" than these hooks with the option to view the modified files,

Answer (score 0):

I would develop a wrapper bash or Python scripts to do your current work including fetch and comparison and relevant actions. For instance,

```py
import git

Repo = git.Repo(".")

for remote in repo.remotes: # Fetching all remote
    remote.fetch()

if repo_git_diff_has_npm(Repo, "HEAD", "origin/main"): # Your comparison logic
    # Your command to refresh npm
    pass
elif repo_git_diff_has_db(Repo, "HEAD", "origin/main"):
    # Your command to refresh database
    pass
```